# Webview свой дизайн

Tags: java, android, webview

У меня есть браузерная игра написана на php. Возможно ли как-то под него сделать клиент, только со своим дизайном(что б текст и картинки выводились где мне нужно)или проще переписать дизайн браузерной игры?
На сайте видела код, где с помощью `StringBuilder` можно вывести значения, что выводит php-скрипт. Или может быть есть какая-то функция своего дизайна `WebView`.

```
private WebView mWebView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    // включаем поддержку JavaScript
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
URLConnection i1 = new URL("Ссылка на твой сайт N").openConnection();
i1.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "MyBrowser/1.0");
StringBuilder i2 = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader i3 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(i1.getInputStream()));
while (true) {
    String i4 = i3.readLine();
    if (i4 != null) {
        i2.append(i4);
        i2.append(System.lineSeparator());
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
i3.close();
String[] i4 = "".toString().split(" <div class=\"menu\">" + System.lineSeparator() + 
    "       <button>Первая кнопка</button>" + System.lineSeparator() + 
    "       <button>Вторая кнопка</button>" + System.lineSeparator() + 
    "       <button>Третья кнопка</button>" + System.lineSeparator() + 
    "   </div>");
WebView i5 = new WebView(Main.this);
i5.loadData(i4[0] + i4[1], "text/html", null);}}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Android Studio это программа, в которой пишут программы для ОС Android - IDE. А изучать вам скорее всего нужно начинать API Android и Java.

Comment: Что Вы понимаете под своим дизайном?

Comment: Что бы приложение отображало  тот текст с и картинки сайта который мне нужен и в определённом месте. Т.к хочу клиент сделать для браузерной игры